# Conditional compilation in Go

Tags: go, cgo

I'm trying to write a Go [wrapper](https://github.com/deft-code/go-enet) using [CGo](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) for [ENet](https://github.com/lsalzman/enet).

When I tried to compile my wrapper on a Mac the library was older and had a slightly different interface.  99% of the code is the same just a few C calls need to change.

What is the best practice for dealing with a problem like this in Go?
Is there some way to do conditional compilation or conditional imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does not have conditional compilation or conditional imports. Handle the type differences in C code.

[Are the [Go] authors opposed to preprocessing?](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/msg/055c255e18d9b963)

Comment: Go actually does have conditional compilation using filename suffixes as andyBallholm's answer demonstrates.

Comment: Downvoters gonna hate :).  Seriously though, @peterSO has the correct answer for my particular problem.  Turns out the Mac thing is a red herring.  The real issue is with library versions, which can only be detected as a `#define` in the header files.  `_darwin.go` or `_linux.go` would only mask the problem until one of them updated their ENet library with a backward incompatible change.

Answer (score 18):

Separate out the platform-specific stuff into a separate file, e.g. stuff.go

Now replace stuff.go with versions for the different platforms, like stuff_darwin.go (for Mac), stuff_windows.go, stuff_linux.go, etc.

If a file has a suffix like that, the go command will compile it only on the platform specified.

Comment: Documented under "Build Constriants" in the [overview](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#overview) of package go/build.

Comment: Great info and absolutely the right answer for OS incompatibilities.  However the root of my problem is differing library versions so I went with the answer that addressed that directly.